# PyPIまたはTestPyPIで二要素認証（2FA）を行いたい

Tags: pip

PyPIまたはTestPyPIで二要素認証（2FA）を行いたいのですが、その前段階のリカバリコードの認証ができません。

---

img.1 二要素認証(2FA)でリカバリコードの使用を求められる

[image: 二要素認証(2FA)でリカバリコードの使用を求められる]

---

リカバリコード発行までは進みます。しかし、テキストファイルでダウンロードして、その文字列をコピー＆ペーストしても「リカバリコード」「回復コードが無効です」と表示されます。

どのようにすれば2要素認証を登録できますでしょうか。お分かりの方、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

## TestPyPIおよびPyPIのリンク

[TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/)
[PyPI](https://pypi.org/)

### PyPIにおける関連Q&A

[二要素認証とは何ですか？ また、PyPI上ではどのように動作しますか?](https://test.pypi.org/help/#twofa)

## 使用予定の認証アプリケーション（TOTP）

Android端末の[Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=ja&gl=US)（プロプライエタリ）を使用予定

## 画面遷移

---

img.2 リカバリーコードの発行(.txtファイルとしてダウンロード保存)

[image: リカバリーコードの発行]

---

img.3 ダウンロードした.txtファイルの文字列をコピー＆ペースト

[image: ダウンロードした.txtファイルの文字列をコピー＆ペースト]

---

img.4 リカバリーコードが無効となる

[image: リカバリーコードが無効となる]

Comment: リカバリーコードは16進数らしき16桁の文字列だと思いますが、そのようになっていますか？
また、使用するのはその内の一つですが、複数行貼り付けてしまっている、ということはありませんか？

Comment: @mjy  `<使用するのはその内の一つですが、複数行貼り付けてしまっている、ということはありませんか？` 複数行を張り付けておりました。mjy様のご指摘されたとおりに、1行のみCopy&Pasteしたところ、リカバリーコードでの認証がうまくいきました。そのあとの、二要素認証も無事に有効化できました！ご教授いただき、ありがとうございますm(uu)m  まさか、リカバリーコードが**16桁×8個**のセットで発行されているとは、思ってもみなかったです。大助かりです。感謝いたします！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

複数行のリカバリコードから1行のみを選んで貼り付けたところ認証が通りました。

miy様の下記コメントをもって当質問の回答としたいと思います。
ありがとうございました！

> リカバリーコードは16進数らしき16桁の文字列だと思いますが、そのようになっていますか？ また、使用するのはその内の一つですが、複数行貼り付けてしまっている、ということはありませんか？

複数行※1をCopy&Pasteしておりました。ご指摘いただいたとおりに、1行のみを張り付けたところ、リカバリーコードでの認証が通りました。

無事、そのあとの二要素認証(2FA)も有効化できました。

※1 PyPI, TestPyPIは16桁のリカバリーコード(例`259118ef********`)が8個セットで発行されるようです。私は、これを128桁のコード1つと捉えておりました。

#### リカバリコードの認証から二要素認証(2FA)の有効化までの手順

img.1 リカバリコードの認証

[image: リカバリコードの認証]

img.2 二要素認証(2FA)の有効化

[image: 二要素認証(2FA)の有効化]

Answer (score 2):

補足

#### なぜ複数のリカバリーコードが発行されるか

PyPIに限らずこういった種類のリカバリーコードは大抵の場合、複数発行されます。これは、リカバリーコードもある種のワンタイムパスワードだからです。

つまり、コードたちはそれぞれ一度ずつしか使用できません。リカバリーコードが8個の場合は、最大で8回だけリカバリーが可能です。テストで一個使いますから、本番で使えるのは7回分です。リカバリーは稀な作業ですし、通常はリカバリーすれば別のリカバリーコードを発行できるはずなので、これで十分なのです。

Comment: 追加補足のご回答をいただきありがとうございます！テスト使用を最低1回行う前提だということ、ですね。言われてみれば、当たり前の仕様であると思えますが、できれば、PyPIやTestPyPIの画面遷移のいずれかの場所で「8個のコードが発行されます」と数字を出して説明して欲しかったです。英語の説明では、複数形で"codes"と記載があるので、まったく説明がないわけではないのですが、読み飛ばしておりました……